# How to check the integrity of a SQL Server compressed backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, compression

Is there a short T-SQL query or command line option to check the integrity of a SQL Server backup created with "compressed" option?

I need it to make sure I downloaded it correctly from network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
restore verifyonly from disk = 'D:\sample.bak';
```

Comment: The backup set on file 1 is valid.
:)